# After throwing an Intent to a PDF app, my activity is finished

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I'm having an issue trying to open files (can be .jpg or .pdf, mostyl .pdf) this is the code that I use to launch the `Intent`:

```
public static void openFile(Context context, File aFile) throws ActivityNotFoundException {
        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        mLogger.info("Opening file " + aFile.getName());
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String[] nameParts = aFile.getName().split("\\.");
        String namePart = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
        mLogger.info("Searching activity for MIME type " + namePart);

        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(namePart);
        newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(aFile), mimeType);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    }
```

I've already tried changing the flags like:

No flags at all.

`newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

`newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

`newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

The weird thing is that somethimes works (doesn't close the Activity from where I launched the intent) and some times does (I press back being in the PDF app, and then when I come back, I'm in the Activity previous to the one where I lauched the intent)

I don't know what other thing I can do, I'm starting to think that is some device related problem. My device is a Moto G.

BTW, this happens with the two kind of files, jpg. and pdf. It's the same, I'm mean, I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the way that I'm setting the flags or It's some kind of device related problem. I don't think that this is a problem related to the applications that I use to open the files.

**EDIT**

Added the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="TOP_SECRET_SORRY">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <!-- Optional permission for reliable local dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:name=".app.NAME"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
         dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />


        <activity
            android:name=".app.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_login"></activity>
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".app.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".app.activities.DisclaimerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_disclaimer"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".app.activities.SubCategoriesListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_file_categories"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".app.activities.SubCategoriesDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/online_file_list">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".app.activities.UatTestingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_uat_testing"></activity>

        <service
            android:name=".app.services.SyncService"
            android:process="com.SOME_COMPANY.SOME_APP.app.services.SyncService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".app.receivers.Boot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name=".utils.MultiProcessShared"
            android:authorities="com.COMPANY.SOME_APP.PREFERENCE_AUTHORITY"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`SubcategoryDetailActivity` is the one whose context I use to launch the intent.

Comment: Could it be that the activity has the "no history" flag set? I think it has sth to do with the flags of the acitvity you launch it from, and not the intent you call in it.

Comment: No, sorry, all my activities are pretty simple, I'll update my post with the manifest inclided.

Comment: so could it be that you launch the activity with manually set flags? so far everything looks normal.

Comment: Sorry nothing like that, I think that maybe could be that my devices runs out of memory and ends up killing my activity, but well... I just wanna to be sure.

Comment: out of memory should cause the activity to be started again with oncreate, your activity is just thrown out, which seems unusual

Comment: @bleeding182 Please, feel free to ask me any more info about my code

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: @bleeding182 I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I used this flag:

`newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

IDK why but if someone can explain it to me I'll gladly accept that answer.